# HTML5 required validation not working [Duplicated]

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I'm using HTML 5 for validating fields.I'm submitting the form using javascript on a button click

But the validation doesn't work on my pc fire fox,it work only on my pc chrome.
also it d'osent work in the integration server with both chrome and fire fox
This is the HTML code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group-form col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
<label class="text-hide" for="name"></label>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Nom" name="nom" required />
</div>
```

My google chrome version is Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit).
My firefox version is 45.6.0.

**Edit** 
this is my JS code:

```
var args = 'ct_nom=' + nom ;
var $myForm = $('#form-contact'); $.get("adresse of the web service" + args, function (data) {
$myForm.submit();
 }).fail(function () {
$myForm.submit();
});
```

Comment: please include javascript code too in you question

Comment: Firefox compatibility start from 4.0, how are you submitting your form fields? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: Try
`<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Nom" name="nom" required="required" />`

Also, make sure you have set submit button as `<input type="submit" />

Answer (score 0):

In the validation of the form i found this line of code who causes the problem

`event.preventDefault();`

after removing this line the problem disapper